# Restore-Spsite -Force not working

Tags: 2013, powershell, restore

I'm quite new to SP and while trying to restore a site collection (same version) to a new area I get the another site collection already exists, choose a new url or use -Force error. Which would be fine if I wasn't already using -Force.

I assume that I am forgetting something/leaving something out when I run the cmdlt.

What I enter is as follows:

```
Restore-Spsite -Identity http://<urlname> -Path C:\backup.bak -Force
```

The above is being run in the sharepoint management shell.

**Update**
Also if this changes anything I am trying to restore the / of the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind two things before making restore of existing site collection.

- you should create a new content database and restore the site in that dB using database parameter. If both source and destination site collections are in same webapplication.
- site collection I'd remain same if you are using the backup n restore. Other alternative is using import n export but that have own limitation.

So you should either restore site collection in different Web application or create a new content dB

before

Answer (score 0):

The Restore-SPSite cmdlet performs a restoration of the site collection to a location specified by the Identity parameter. A content database may only contain one copy of a site collection. If a site collection is backed up and restored to a different URL location within the same Web application, an additional content database must be available to hold the restored copy of the site collection.

A site collection does not have to already exist at the URL location to perform a restore. However, you must specify a valid URL location that a site collection can be created. If a site collection already exists at the specified URL location, you must specify the Force parameter to overwrite it.

When you Restore site collection make sure you are restoring it to a different URL. Else you should use `-Force` parameter.

Comment: I am already trying to use  -Force.

What I am entering in is as follows: Restore-Spsite -Identity http://<urlname> -Path C:\backup.bak -Force

Please note that <urlname> is the / of the server